# QuickBooks API request returning "Premature end of file", error code -2001

Tags: xml, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am making calls to the QuickBooks API, I have many other queries that are working correctly so I am confident that it is not something with my OAuth library or any of the basic framework.  But this is my first attempt to do a filter query, so it is probably something specific to this type of query.  I am making a POST request to https://services.intuit.com/sb/customer/v2/realmid (yes, using my real realm id), with the following xml as the body of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomerQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<FirstLastInside>bla</FirstLastInside>
</CustomerQuery>
```

This is the response that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<Error RequestId="3f7113681b0749fc97644b6c4486985f">
<RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
<ProcessedTime>2013-07-01T16:08:40.230Z</ProcessedTime>
<ErrorCode>-2001</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDesc>Premature end of file.</ErrorDesc>
</Error>
</RestResponse>
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

The correct URL is  https://services.intuit.com/sb/customer/v2/{realmid}. So @Blair you did have the correct URL. The error is a valid error being returned by intuit servers.

The API explorer is there to try out your credentials and tokens. You can use those tokens in your oauth library and compare to make sure your post is similar to what is being posted in the api explorer. Obviously the oauth header itself that is generated will not match but that is ok.

The idea is to compare what you are posting in your header and payload with what apiexplorer is doing to give you better insight into the problem. Please try that and let us know if it solved the issue.

Comment: Using the XML copy/pasted from my original question, the API Explorer works just fine (when logged into the API Explorer using the credentials and tokens from my app), and I get the response XML as expected.  Which only confuses me more, because as I said I am making many other calls to the API without problems, which leads me to believe that my basic mechanics of creating a proper query are correct, and when use the XML in API Explorer it works, which would lead me to believe that the XML I am sending is correct.  I don't know what else to look at to see what may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this call using ApiExplorer tool(QBD).

Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

PFB snapshot

[image]

Please let me know if it works for you.

**EDIT** Adding endpoint and post body. It worked fine

```
Endpoint - https://services.intuit.com/sb/customer/v2/<relam-id>
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <FirstLastInside>Manas</FirstLastInside>
</CustomerQuery>
```

Comment: Yes, it actually does work when I use the API Explorer.  However the correct endpoint from MY app cannot be https://internal.services.lvdc.intuit.com/sb/customer/v2/[relam_id], that is not a public domain name and does not resolve from an nslookup, and my app will be unable to send a request to it.